# How to capitalize all the words in a sentence except some words?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

i need to capitalize the all the words in a sentence expect some words.

Eg:

`ABOUT UNICORN TECHNOLOGIES`

Output :

`About unicorn technologies`

Here the words Unicorn, Technologies may come in capitalize or uppercase or smallcase but if these value comes in any sentence, i need to convert this into smaller case.

Example sentences are,

`ANDRII IS GOOD IN JS TECHNOLOGIES`

`THIS HORSE LOOKS LIKE A UNICORN`

output:

`Andrii Is Good In Js technologies`

`This Horse Looks Like A unicorn`

I tried to achieve this with lodash. But i clouldnt do that :(

Help me to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do we decide which woulds should be capitalized

Comment: "I tried to achieve this with lodash." - what exactly did you try? "But it doesnt work" - what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: expect technologies & unicorn all of the other words needs to be capitalized whereas this two has to be in smallcase

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @DhanushKumarS Other words need to be in titlecase? Or others words don't change? In your question other words change too.

Comment: Others words needs to be in titlecase

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `String#split` `Array#map` and `Array#join`

Split the sentence by spaces and for every word if the word is present in the `Set` simply lowercase it and if it is not change it to titlecase.

```js
const 
  strs = new Set(["ABOUT", "UNICORN", "TECHNOLOGIES"]),
  sentence = "ANDRII IS GOOD IN JS TECHNOLOGIES",
  res = sentence
    .split(" ")
    .map((w) =>
      strs.has(w.toUpperCase())
        ? w.toLowerCase()
        : w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1).split().map((c) => c.toLowerCase())
    )
    .join(" ");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @DhanushKumarS Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You basically lowercase everything first, then check if each word is one of the special keywords.  If so just return, if not then uppercase the first letter and return.

Below is an example.  I've also made it so it keeps the line breaks, as your examples seems to be a multi-line input.

```js
const keywords = new Set( ['technologies','unicorn']);

const lines = `ANDRII IS GOOD IN JS TECHNOLOGIES

THIS HORSE LOOKS LIKE A UNICORN`.split("\n");

function normalizeCase(t) {
  const words = t.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  return words.map(w => 
    keywords.has(w) 
     ? w
     : w[0] 
        ? w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)
        : ''        
    ).join(' ');
}

const newLines =
  lines.map(l => normalizeCase(l));
  
console.log(newLines.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all no spacing characters and check for the special words with an object.

```js
const nice = s => s.replace(/\S+/g, s => ({ UNICORN : 'unicorn', TECHNOLOGIES: 'technologies' }[s] || s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase()));

console.log(nice('ABOUT UNICORN TECHNOLOGIES'));
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a list of the words you want to be lowercase and use it while iterating through the string, if the current word is on the list, then it's lowercase, otherwise, it's titlecase.

**Working example**

```js
const capitalizeExc = (string, exceptions) => {
  const words = string.split(' ')
  exceptions = exceptions.toLowerCase()
  const result = words.map((word) => {
    if (exceptions.includes(word.toLowerCase())) {
      return word.toLowerCase()
    } else {
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +  word.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    }
  }).join(' ')
  return result
}

console.log(capitalizeExc('ANDRII IS GOOD IN JS TECHNOLOGIES', 'technologies unicorn'))
```

**More information**

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Of course, you should try to optimize the performance of it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "ANDRII IS GOOD IN JS TECHNOLOGIES TECHNOLOGIESX";
a = a.replace(/\b(technologies\b|unicorn\b)?(?:([^\s])([^\s]*)\b)?/gi, (_,b,c,d) => {
   b = b ?  b.toLowerCase() : "";
   c = c ?  c.toUpperCase() : "";
   d = d ?  d.toLowerCase() : "";
   return b + c + d;
});
console.log(a);
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(technologies\b|unicorn\b)?`: First capture group that captures the word if the word is technology or unicorn (case insensitive). `\b` is used to distinguish TECHNOLOGIES from TECHNOLOGIESX.
- `(?:([^\s])([^\s]*)\b)?`: Non capturing group.

  - `([^\s])`: Second capturing group captures the first letter of a word if the word is not technology or unicorn (case insensitive).
  - `([^\s]*)`: Third capturing group captures the rest the word if the word is not technology or unicorn (case insensitive)